# Access country IP restricted web from Azure

Tags: security, azure, ip, azure-webjobs

I have a WebJob that runs in Azure (North Europe - guess it's Ireland).
It access a danish website, which is IP restricted to only danish IP's.
Therefore Azure cannot access it of cause.

It gets data to be populated on a danish website, hosted in Azure, so it is all danish/danish you could say - it just runs in Azure.

Any ideas for how I can make this work - if possible?

Getting the website to open for Azure IP's etc. is not an option.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible get a Danish IP address for your WebJob. You get the IP address of the region from where you're running your WebJob.

Comment: Yeah, that's sadly also my conclusion. I was just thinking there might be a work around, as I could see a lot of systems might have this problem, and I guess Azure don't want Azure my it self to be a limitation in that sense :)